# how to show alternate red and green color of row?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-table

I am using `react table` in react.I learn from here 
https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#codesandbox-examples
and from here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table

I want to show my rows alternate color "red" and "green" having a border of black on each cell.can we show in react table?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-banzai-zp54o

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the background to green then using the `nth-of-type` selector you can target `even` rows and style their background red. You could also use `odd` to do this the other way around.

```css
.rt-tr-group{
  background: green;
}
.rt-tr-group:nth-of-type(even){
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="rt-tbody" style="min-width: 200px;"><div class="rt-tr-group" role="rowgroup"><div class="rt-tr -odd" role="row"><div class="rt-td" role="gridcell" style="flex: 100 0 auto; width: 100px;">naveen</div><div class="rt-td" role="gridcell" style="flex: 100 0 auto; width: 100px;"><div><span class="number">14</span><br><span class="number">jgjg</span></div></div></div></div><div class="rt-tr-group" role="rowgroup"><div class="rt-tr -even" role="row"><div class="rt-td" role="gridcell" style="flex: 100 0 auto; width: 100px;">test</div><div class="rt-td" role="gridcell" style="flex: 100 0 auto; width: 100px;"><div><span class="number">18</span><br><span class="number">jggkhkg</span></div></div></div></div><div class="rt-tr-group" role="rowgroup"><div class="rt-tr -odd" role="row"><div class="rt-td" role="gridcell" style="flex: 100 0 auto; width: 100px;">naveen</div><div class="rt-td" role="gridcell" style="flex: 100 0 auto; width: 100px;"><div><span class="number">14</span><br><span class="number">jgjg</span></div></div></div></div><div class="rt-tr-group" role="rowgroup"><div class="rt-tr -even" role="row"><div class="rt-td" role="gridcell" style="flex: 100 0 auto; width: 100px;">test</div><div class="rt-td" role="gridcell" style="flex: 100 0 auto; width: 100px;"><div><span class="number">18</span><br><span class="number">jggkhkg</span></div></div></div></div></div>
```

updated sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/bu45o?fontsize=14

Comment: thanks for answer ...see my update.. i want like this

Comment: backborder should be in between a cell

Comment: I have answered your question, the basic style is there if you want to get a specific border style that's your job, StackOverflow is not a code writing service